# query string then insert in anchor using parse

Tags: javascript, html, string, parse-platform

I am using Parse to retrieve values stored in a database. I can successfully retrieve image data and render it to the DOM, however, I am having trouble getting a string which consists of a web address and inserting it into an `<a>` tag. Currently, I get an "error loading page" message. I'm not sure what I've done wrong? Heres the main part of my code:

```
query.find({
    success:function(results) {
    var s = "";
    for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
        //Lame - should be using a template
        s += "<p>";
        var pic = results[i].get("image");
        var address = results[i].get("address");

        if(pic) {
            s += "<br/><a href='"+address+"'><img src='" + pic.url() + "'></a>";
        }
        s += "</p>";
    }
    $("#home2 div[data-role=content]").html(s);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `results[i].get("address")` returns a string?

Comment: "address" is the Id name, but it is actually returning "undefined" right now

Comment: Then the problem might be on the Parse server side. It's not fetching that value from your database. What does your actual query look like?

Comment: Wow, I was querying the wrong database. Thanks.